# Why can't we define function inside the main function?

Tags: c

In the following program, I try to call the function `n()` and inside `n()`, try to call `m()` function which is defined in the `main` function, but when I compile, I get the error below:

> ```
> In function `n':
> (.text+0xa): undefined reference to `m'
> error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Why do I get an error? Please explain.

The code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void m();
void n()
{
    m();
}

void main()
{
    n();
    void m()
    {
        printf("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: `m` is inside your main function. Move it outside!

Comment: I know, but why i got error?

Comment: "I know" - apparently not. This code shouldn't even compile, much less fail at link-time (which is the error).

Comment: `void main` is wrong. `main` should return `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`m` is defined inside of `main`. In standard C, that's not allowed (you can't define a function within another function).

Some compilers (e.g. gcc) allow it as an extension. But then the function is *local*, i.e. `m` only exists within `main` and can't be seen from the outside. Similarly, variables defined within a function are local to that function and can't be seen from the outside.

Your `void m();` declaration at the top claims that a (global) function called `m` exists, but it doesn't. That's why you get the linker error.

Answer (score 6):

You can not implement a function within the scope of another function in standard C. Move the implementation of `m()` out of your main.

The code you posted should not compile at all; though, the error you get is because the linker `ld` can not find the implementation of `m`. The function can be used because you *declared* it, but the *implementation* is missing and thus can not be linked.

Also note that your `main` function shall return a value of type `int`. Using `void` will make your program return an arbitrary value from which the operating system/shell can't conclude whether execution was successful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void m();

void n() {
    m();
}

int main() {
    n();
    return 0;
}

void m() {
    printf("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the function declaration of `m()` outside of the `main()` method.